# EXCEL VBA HTML Click button then click drop down option

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

I asked a question here originally  [Excel VBA HTML Click Button/Hyperlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52770576/excel-vba-html-click-button-hyperlinks) but editted and changed and kinda got lost.. After hours and hours of further research and reviewing my webpage, I have found another way to get to my desired outcome.

As clicking a hyperlink doesn't seem to work, there is another button that I can click that has a drop down option that I then need to also click to get to the same point (as the original hyperlink method).

The 'Inspect Elements' of the button and the drop down are below. Also my updated code follows.

Outcome - Click on button "Go To" then select drop down option 'Details'..

Also, please ignore sendkeys, I know they are a last resort but for the time, it works.

Inspect Element "Go To":

```
<a title="Go To - Menu button - To open the menu press spacebar" class="urTbarBtnStd" id="SRES2_BUT_GOTO" onkeypress="sapUrMapi_ToolbarButton_openMenu('SRES2_BUT_GOTO',event);return false;" onclick="sapUrMapi_ToolbarButton_openMenu('SRES2_BUT_GOTO',event);return false;" href="javascript:void(0);" ct="ToolbarButton"><span style="white-space: nowrap;">Go To&nbsp;&nbsp;<img align="baseline" class="urTbarBtnMnuIco" src="1x1"></span></a>
```

Inspect Element "Details":

```
<tr class="urMnuRowOn" id="EDIT_DETAILS" onclick="me.htmlbSL(this,78,'SRES2_GOTO:onSelectPopupMenuItem','','EDIT_DETAILS','Details');;me.sapUrMapi_PopupMenu_hideAll();return false;" Idx="0"><td width="17" class="urMnuChk" style="width: 17px;">&nbsp;</td><td width="4" style="width: 4px;">&nbsp;</td><td width="40" class="urMnuTxt" nowrap="" style="width: 40px;"><span style="white-space: nowrap;">Details</span></td><td width="15" class="urMnuSub" style="width: 15px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

```
Sub TPMRebates()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    Dim aEle As Object 'HTMLLinkElement
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim result As String
    Dim Link As Object
    Dim ElementCol As Object
    Dim wkbSourceWB As Workbook
    Dim SourceShtClm As Worksheet

    Set wkbSourceWB = ThisWorkbook     'Set workbook
    Set SourceShtClm = wkbSourceWB.Sheets("Claim Summary")

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate "<very long intranet website>"

    Do While objIE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 4) 'wait 4 sec

    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Enter}"

    Application.Wait Time + TimeSerial(0, 0, 6)

    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
    SendKeys "{Tab}"
    Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)


    SourceShtClm.Range("N4").Copy

    SendKeys "^v"

    SendKeys "{Enter}"

    Application.Wait Time + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)

    '*****************************
    '
    'This is where I need the code to click 'go to' then 'details'
    '
    '*****************************

    'Have tried things like objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    'For Each Link In ElementCol
    '    Debug.Print Link.innerText
    '    If Link.innerText Like "Go To - Menu button - To open the menu press spacebar" Then
    '        Link.Click
    '        Exit For
    '    End If
    'Next Link
    '
    '
    'Also tried things like; objIE.document.getElementsByID("SRES2_BUT_GOTO").Click also .Focus but nothing works


End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try FireEvent "onkeypress" etc?

Comment: Just tried objIE.document.getElementsByID("SRES2_BUT_GOTO").FireEvent "onkeypress" Got runtime error 438

Comment: getelementbyid without s

Comment: Unfortunately still runtime error, this time 424.

Comment: Is the element within an iframe/frame?

Comment: Not sure... But the more I research I think it is.. I scroll up thru the elements and it sits under the broad frame name="crmA"

Comment: Literally spent hrs and days on this trying to get it to work...

Comment: Then you need to access that first. It is super late here as is BST time zone. I can advise further tomorrow.

Comment: I will research this and try my luck.. Thx for the help

Comment: Ok. You will need something lol getElementsByTagName(“frame”)(0).contentDocument.getElementById.  The “” are the wrong time cos on mobile. The index 0 needs to be the right frame index so could be 1 etc...... you will find examples on SO.

Comment: I got it to work.. I viewed ths site: https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/141023-vba-to-click-webpage-button-with-onmouseover-and-inside-a-frame Post #2 Code...

Comment: The issue that I had is that when inspecting elements, you really need to view/review where that element sits. QHarr thanks for leading me back on the right direction...

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim frame As HTMLFrameElement
Dim img As HTMLImg

Set HTMLdoc = objIE.document
Set frame = HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("crmA")(0)
Set HTMLdoc = frame.contentDocument
Set img = HTMLdoc.getElementById("SRES2_BUT_GOTO")
img.Click
```